# Ada - Any defined behavior for incrementing past end of range?

Tags: range, ada

If I define a range in ADA as being from 1 .. 1000, is there a defined behavior by the ADA spec if I increment past 1000?

For example:

```
type Index is range 1..1000;

idx : Index := 1;

procedure Increment is 
begin
  idx := idx + 1;
end
```

What should I expect to happen once I call Increment with idx = 1000?

- Wraps around (idx = 1)
- Out of Range exception
- Undefined behavior
- Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program will fail with a [`CONSTRAINT_ERROR`](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-11-01.html). However, this is not because you eventually try to set `idx` to 1001. Rather is its initial value of 0 not within your predefined range either. Thankfully, the compiler will already warn you at compile time about this fact.

If you had set `idx` to a permitted value and then incremented it beyond its upper limit in a way the compiler cannot statically detect, again `CONSTRAINT_ERROR` will be raised (but there won't be any hint at compile time).
This error is technically an [exception](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-11-02.html) which you can handle like any other exception in that language.

*Note:* I intentionally linked to the ancient Ada '83 specs above to show that this behavior has been part of the language since the beginning of time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  The initial value of 0 was a mistake in my example.  I think I was thinking of the `mod` type when I thought it would possibly wrap around.

Comment: For the modular type `type index is mod 1000;` it would wrap round. I think modular types were added in Ada-95.

Comment: Note that, in the past (pre ada2012?), the gnat compiler without the switch -gnato won't detect the overflow (in other words, it's not a conforming Ada compiler without that switch).

Comment: I think that the range would still be checked when assigning, even when the computation of `idx + 1` had overflowed and overflow was not to be detected.